# Unresolved import csv Pydev Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a love-hate relationship with Pydev on Eclipse. For some reason it is now telling me that it has an unresolved import on the code:

```
import csv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peterstannett/Documents/Programming/python/eclipse/workspace/myFirstPydev/csv.py", line 1, in <module>
import csv
  File "/Users/peterstannett/Documents/Programming/python/eclipse/workspace/myFirstPydev/csv.py", line 3, in <module>
cr = csv.reader(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

It was working fine a few days ago I'm sure!

So I started to look at the interpreter and the path where the csv.py file should be and I can see in the System PYTHONPATH that it has the /lib/python2.7 where the csv.py file is held yet I still get an error.

[image]

Would someone please help me resolve this as it is most frustrating!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your file is called `csv.py`, it is found before the csv module from the standard library when you `import csv`. Rename your file to something like `myCsv.py` to resolve the ambiguity.